# Is nfc card emulation mode passive or Active?

Tags: android, nfc

I know that during card emulation mode the phone behaves exactly in  the same way as a contact-less payment plastic smartcard. So  is this "smartcard-phone" just as a NFC tag?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take your time to read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

It's passive.

Question answered.